# Problems with IOException on Files resources JAVA

Tags: java, resources, jframe, ioexception

I have serius problems whenI work with files in Java and when I export the proyect after to .jar.
This is my dependence tree:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f99yl.jpg

I use Eclipse. All works fine except when  it builds the .jar for execute it in other computers.
Cabecera.txt and proc.txt files are used in this code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int accion=generaScript(modelLogin, modelGroups);
         if(accion==1){

            try {
                String s1="src\\resources\\textFiles\\cabecera.txt";
                String s2="src\\resources\\textFiles\\proc.txt";

                File cabecera = new File(s1));
                System.out.println(s1.length());
                File finale = new File(s2) ;

                //File s = generaScriptFinal(cabecera, finale, getVariablePrio());
                System.out.println(s2.length());
                File s = generaScriptFinal(f, finale, getVariablePrio());
                //File s = generaScriptFinal(cabecera, finale, getVariablePrio());
```

This is it the method "generaScriptFinal" where I merge both files and some strings more in a new file.

```
File generaScriptFinal(File cabecera, File procedimiento, String varPrio) throws IOException{




    File ftemp = File.createTempFile("mificheroTemporal", null);
    Pen pilot = new Pen(ftemp.getPath());

    pilot.mergeto(cabecera.getPath());

    for(int i=0; i<modelLogin.size();i++){
        pilot.writeSentenciaIF(modelLogin.get(i), Integer.parseInt(modelGroups.get(i)));
    }

    pilot.consultaVarBD(varPrio);
    pilot.mergeto(procedimiento.getPath());
    pilot.actualizaVarBD(varPrio);
    pilot.finalizaScript();
    pilot.exe_dropScript();
    pilot.ponerCapuchaPen();

    return pilot.getFichero();


}
```

Pilot is an object thats allow to write in a file. In this case, I merge "cabecera.txt", "proc.txt" and other string:

```
public class Pen {

private String ruta;
private File archivo=null; 
private FileWriter salida;
private BufferedWriter escribe;


//Constructor
public  Pen (String Path) throws IOException{
    //Crea un fichero a partir de una ruta con un printWriter para poder escribir.
    this.ruta=Path;

    try{
         archivo = new File(this.ruta);
         salida = new FileWriter(archivo);
         escribe = new BufferedWriter(salida);

    }catch
        (IOException e){};

}
public void mergeto(String filePath) throws IOException{
    File tmp = new File(filePath);
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(tmp);
    BufferedReader gafas = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = null;
    this.escribe.newLine();
    while((line=gafas.readLine())!=null){
        this.escribe.write(line);
        this.escribe.newLine();
    }
    gafas.close();

}
```

As you can see, I created a Resources Folder. I think is good when it does the "package" (build the jar) and also I try to call them with "-this.getClass().getResource("cabecera.txt").getPath()-" but it isn't works in eclipse and out of eclipse.
If i use the path directly in a String, in Eclipse works fine but out of Eclipse (executing the .jar) not.
The error is an IOException (java.nullpointerException).
I can't understand what are happening...
I appreciate all the support that you can give me. I need finish my proyect.
If you need more information, please do not hesitate to tell me!
Thanks!

Comment: Try `resources\textFiles\cabecera.txt`

Comment: thanks!! and sorry for the dupplication... it's difficult to find the solution!